# Incorrectly awarded Archaeologist badge on meta-site

Tags: bug, badge-progress, edit-badges

Last week I received the Archaeologist badge on Sustainability Meta, but I don't think that's correct.

I have [209 revisions in total](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/users/99/thelper?tab=activity&sort=revisions), but the vast majority (144 revisions to be precise) are on 1 particular question titled '[Site statistics](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/site-statistics)'. This is a community-wiki question which I edit bi-weekly, so it should not count. This means that at best 65 revisions could count towards the badge, but I'm sure most edits where on posts that were not inactive for 6 months. This is confirmed by [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.sustainability/query/119332/edits-qualifying-for-archaeologist-badge-progress?userid=99) that shows only 3 of my edits qualify towards the badge.

So why did I get the Archaeologist badge? It looks like a bug.

Comment: [My query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.sustainability/query/1080174/archaeologist-progress-single-site?AccountId=384624) is probably more accurate (adding the [featured] tag to a question does not count towards the badge) but still shows only 1 post which qualifies.